# Windows - Extracted Ruby Files missing

Tags: windows-10, ruby

I am trying to install Ruby 2.0.0, however when I run the extractor the files never appear. I have tried both the x64 and 32 bit packages. I have even tried newer and older versions of Ruby. When I run the installer it says it was successful, however the folder is never there. If I attempt to reinstall it, then go to the file viewer to choose a installation path, it shows the folder there. I have also tried running ruby commands in a command prompt and get `'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: are you running the installer as admin?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes.